# Nothing happens when trying to call python script from a PHP file on my localhost

Tags: php, python, localhost, ubuntu-13.04

This are the lines in question in my php file:

```
$eventid_arg = $_REQUEST['eventid'];
$pyresponse_str = system('python s_scrape.py $eventid_arg', $retval);
```

And I have done the following for s_scrape.py:

```
1- placed it in the same localhost folder as the php file. 
2- chown changed to www-data:www-data
3- chmod changed to 777 on both the .py and .pyc
4- made sure '#!/usr/bin/env python' is on the python file
```

Comment: can you try adding the complete path to python in your system call too?

Comment: I've tried - how would i know if its accurate?

Answer (score 1):

I might be slightly off here but perhaps:

```
$pyresponse_str = system('python s_scrape.py $eventid_arg', $retval);
```

Simply needs double quotes to recognize $eventid_arg ?

```
$pyresponse_str = system("python s_scrape.py $eventid_arg", $retval);
```

Comment: There was no effect.  I'm going to try a base- case scenario, no argument and strip everything else from the php.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [system()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.system.php) only if the python has no return output. You should use [popen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) if you intend on using stdin or stdout.

As indicated by the [popen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) documentation, this "returns a file pointer identical to that returned by fopen(), except that it is unidirectional (may only be used for reading or writing) and must be closed with pclose()."